# Firebase: .observeEventType .Value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is some swift code related to Firebase, which is not working as I expect and I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

```
    let firebaseRootReference = Firebase(url:"https://mywonderfulapp.firebaseio.com/“),
    dataRef = firebaseRootReference.childByAppendingPath(“MyList")
    dataRef = dataRef.childByAppendingPath(key) // key is a String object.

    dataRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        for dataItem in snapshot.children {
            let dataKey = (dataItem as? FDataSnapshot)!.key,
            dataVal = (dataItem as? FDataSnapshot)!.value.objectForKey("name") as! String
            print("Found (observeEventType) : \(dataKey) -> \(dataVal)")
        }

        }, withCancelBlock: { error in
            print(error.description)
    })
```

The code above prints something like the following in the debugger console:

```
Found (observeEventType) : SOME-KEY -> SOME-DATA
```

This is perfectly OK and this is what I expect in a normal situation.
But even when I put my device in flight mode in order to stop the network, it still prints the same kind of things.
Of course I have checked the server side to confirm that nothing has been written.

In other words the block inside dataRef.observeEventType is called though nothing has been written to the server.

It does not trace what has been indeed written on the server, but what would have been written if it was connected.
So what am I missing? Probably not checking what I should?

Note that I see no problem when normally connected to the network.

Comment: try onDisconnect methods

Comment: How would I use this onDisconnect method in my case?
And what is wrong with what I did?

Comment: I am not trying to do anything specific when the user disconnects.

Comment: you means the block called by changing net ?

Comment: "Why do I get data reported as if it had been written to the server when it has not?" is my only question.

Comment: Are you using FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true ? If so this will save a JSON file locally when your offline

Comment: Oh!? I see, that sounds like a possible explanation. I had never heard about FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled, so I must be using whatever the default is. Anyway, so what I see is a report about what is happening locally and not what is happening on the server (as I thought)?
I will try to change this persistenceEnabled thing and see.

Comment: It appears Firebase.defaultConfig().persistenceEnabled is false in my app. So I guess the explanation does not fit here.

Comment: I did some further testing. On the network, even after I reestablish the connection there is no update, which in my understanding is consistent with the fact that Firebase.defaultConfig().persistenceEnabled is false. But that still leaves unexplained the issue I brought in my post.

Answer (score 0):

there are some describe about the base func `setValue(value: AnyObject!)`

- The effect of the write will be visible immediately and the corresponding
  events will be triggered. Synchronization of the data to the Firebase 
  servers will also be started.

so the observe will be triggered before the Synchronization or the same time

Comment: Sorry it seems like my question is not clear. I have read about onDisconnect() (after your first comment) in the Firebase documentation, but I do not really see how I can use it. One more important point is that I have no problem at all to write on the server. This is working fine. My issue is about understanding what happens when I am not connected.

Comment: you do nothing while not connected ? I'm confused about it